# Loading elements in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I am loading some comments in via ajax, default is 5 onload then the user can request more if they want.

This is more a question of good practice.

Where is the best place to build to html elements that will be displayed on the page.

Should I build them up in the javascript file then display them?

I am using Yii framework if this is any help.

Comment: Just append the html created in javascript to a layer in your page

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly a number of ways you can achieve this. I've faced a similar issue before (also related to a Comments system) and what I did was to create a custom Widget and simply load it in the controller. Widgets can have view files which will be loaded upon request and you can simply inject the output into a specific place in your page. 
Here's what I have in my code:

/protected/widgets/LoadComments.php

```
class LoadComments extends CWidget {

    public $offset;
    public $limit;
    public $comments;

    public function run() {
        //(some offset and limit logic here)
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        // some criteria definitions here (...)

        $this->comments = Comment::model()->findAll($criteria);

        $this->render('listComments', array());
    }
}
```

/protected/controllers/CommentController.php

```
public function actionListComments($offset = 0, $limit = 10) {
    $this->widget("application.widgets.LoadComments", array(
       "offset" => $offset,
       "limit" => $limit,
    ));
}
```

/protected/views/comments.php

```
<div id="comments"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: { offset : 0, limit : 10},
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/comment/listComments');?>',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#comments').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```